# i would like to check a double figure number that inserted into the textbox,

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textchanged

i would like to check a double figure  number that inserted into the textbox, but i can't put double figure number since this event jump after the first figure inserted. what can i do to solve this problem?

```
private void TablesNumberRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CheckValidationOfTableNumber();
}
```

Comment: huh?  it's not clear what you are asking.  what is the actual vs. desired behavior?  where's the code for your CheckValidationOfTableNumber function?

Comment: stick an if statement around it and check how many characters are there before calling your validation method. the event will fire every time but will only validate when it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of validating after each character entered, use the `RichTextBox` [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to verify the validity of the input.

It will be raised only when the user attempts to leave the control.